# Sending html mails with PHP

Tags: php, email

So i am using xmail php class to send my mails.

Now that i have quite some users on my site, some user's mail does not have html enabled for their emails. Is there any way I can write a message at the top of the email, or even show another email content, if they view it as text/plain?

If not, what are my options, what can I do? I know one option and that is sending text/plain mails, but these wont even allow html anchor links, which I need for e.g activation mails..

Comment: Many email clients will automatically convert strings beginning "http://" into hyperlinks in text/plain emails so that's not a complete handicap (and you can always say something to the effect of "copy this link into your browser's address bar").

Comment: Oh - and one other thing with HTML emails, I've found the most reliable way to get them to display "properly" is to get really old skool with it; plain HTML 4 - no CSS! So you have to dredge up all those horrible old tricks like spacer gifs and use font tags :\

Answer (score 3):

You can send multi-part emails. One part is HTML and then there is a fallback of plain text for non HTML email clients. [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) makes this easy to do.

Comment: Not entirely infallible as I've known email clients to fall over with multipart (it ends up displaying both the text/plain and text/html as plain text one below the other with all the gory html tags on display) - so you should put the text/plain content _before_ the text/html. This is probably the best solution though.

Comment: Can you show an example how easy it is to do with PHPMailer, thanks

Comment: [This tutorial](http://www.askapache.com/php/phpfreaks-eric-rosebrocks-phpmailer-tutorial.html#Sending_HTML_Mail_PHP_PHPMailer) demonstrates it well.

Comment: +1 for using a mailing library. I use [Swift](http://swiftmailer.org/), just to give another option.